# Optimizing query between two databases

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to run a query that joins tables from two SQL Server databases on the same server. They use different collation, and the only available key to join them is a text string of 20 characters.

So I set up my query like this:

```
select * 
from (subquery in DB1) s
inner join DB2.table on DB2.table.key COLLATE Finnish_Swedish_CI_AS = s.key
...some extra joins from DB2
...some conditions
...sort by DB2.table.key
```

The first subquery is pretty hefty. By itself, it takes about 10 minutes to run.  If I copy/paste the results in the "key" field to create a static list for the second part of the query (essentially querying each database separately), it runs in a few seconds. But when I run the combined query, it can run for an hour and still not finish.

Why might that be, and is there anything I can do to optimize it?

Comment: Well, short of figuring out why any query takes 10 minutes in the first place, have you considered dumping the results of the first subquery into a #temp table (with the right collation on the key column), and joining to that? Might simplify the query enough to give the optimizer some relief.

Comment: I strongly second Aaron's suggestion.  Often when working with remote databases, materializing the query locally gives the best performance.  Further, you can then add indexes, which can further boost performance.

Comment: You see that `COLLATE` clause there? Yeah, that's going to kill your performance stone dead because it prevents the optimizer from remoting the join condition. Instead it will typically merrily copy over `DB2.table` (or whatever the biggest table is that you *don't* want copied), then do the join. As in, *all* of `DB2.table`. I'd give you advice on how to optimize but the two gentlemen above me have already said it all: split the query up into queries that *only* perform local actions or that funnel a subset of remote data in a temp table, then do your joins on that local temp table.

Comment: Well, the first query has to find the most recent and oldest records within a specific time period for each of 140000 object/record type combinations, out of a table with 250 million records, subtract them, and compare the results to each other.  Doesn't seem all that ridiculous to take 10 minutes, does it?  Or is that still excessive?
I'll try the temp table.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I suspected that the COLLATE was the culprit, but didn't realize it was that inefficient.  That would be particularly awful, given the size of the tables in these databases.  No wonder it got stuck.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, if you put your comment into an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Incidentally, if you happen to know the collations in both cases are compatible (that is, the `COLLATE` isn't strictly necessary for correct results) you can tell the optimizer that: mark the linked server "collation compatible". In this case the optimizer may come up with a better plan -- stress "may", because in my experience this still often goes wrong. What can still trip you up then is the optimizer not having access to statistics -- prior to an update for SQL Server 2012, you needed extensive permissions for this. ...bottom line, you're still usually better off fixing things manually.

Comment: @JeroenMostert So if there aren't any language specific characters or character sorting, then they are "collation compatible"?  I'm joining on serial numbers stored as text, so the strings are actually identical in both tables and would be sorted the same way.

Comment: Yes, that's an obvious case for compatibility. Beware though that this property is global to the linked server connection; you can't selectively turn it off for individual queries. (Though explicitly specifying a collation should work for that case -- but I've never tested this. When I run into trouble with a remote query, my first instinct is to reach for the temp tables, because this tends to give good results quicker than trying to coax the optimizer to do the original remote query well.)

Comment: I do not believe the OP mentioned linked server or remote DB. He said "two DBs on the same server". So the first thing I recommend is to ditch the subqueries and use joins and index the joined columns properly. Turn on output of an actual plan and see what optimizer recommends, then experiment implementing the recommended.

Comment: @ajeh because the joins are on columns with collation that don't match. An index isn't going to help that scenario - at least one side is still going to have to scan.

Comment: I feel silly now -- for some reason I completely missed the explicit "on the same server" part of the question. While everything I've said about distributed queries involving linked servers remains correct, it's also irrelevant to this question. The main problem is probably still the collation override, and temp tables are still a valid workaround. And while creating an index on either column will not help, what will help is creating an index on a computed column with the collation applied. Obviously, such an index would eat up additional storage that may or may not be worth it.

Comment: `Well, the first query has to find the most recent and oldest records within a specific time period for each of 140000 object/record type combinations, out of a table with 250 million records, subtract them, and compare the results to each other. Doesn't seem all that ridiculous to take 10 minutes, does it?` Yes, it does. With proper indexing there is no way that operation should ever take 10 minutes.

Comment: I can't do anything about the indexing (or the collation for that matter) because they aren't "my" databases.  And they aren't optimized for this type of query, because it's just a report my team needs, not something which the program is designed to do.